# Tab bar disappears after push back to a view controller of the tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a **tab bar controller** with four view controllers. In the second view controller I have a table view. Now when the user tabs on a cell of the table view, I do a push to another view controller. When I now tab on my button "back" I do a push segue to the table view again, **but somehow my tab bar disappears**.
I did every push in my storyboard, no coding.

Do you have an idea, how I can solve that problem?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never** go back to a previous view controller with a segue, unless you use an `unwind segue`. When you do a push to "go back" to the table view, you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance, and that instance knows nothing about the tab bar controller. When you push to that other controller, you get a back button by default -- if you use that, it will call `popViewControllerAnimated:` which is what you want to do. If you really want to use a custom back button and a segue, then use an unwind.